# Kotlin Multiplatform: IllegalStateException: Must be main thread

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, koin, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm using `Koin 3.0.0-alpha-4` version and when I'm trying to use injected class by `koin`, then it throws exception for iOS side:
 `KotlinException=kotlin.IllegalStateException: Must be main thread, KotlinExceptionOrigin`
I have a singleton class where I'm initializing objects using koin like that:

```
@ThreadLocal
object ObjectFactory : KoinComponent{
  val appStateRepository: AppStateRepository by inject()
  val appStateRepositoryDemo =  AppStateRepository()
}
```

if I use `appStateRepository`  inside background thread (`Dispatchers.Default`), which is injected by koin, then it throws exception `IllegalStateException: Must be main thread`, but if I use appStateRepositoryDemo than it works fine

Here is a method which  I'm invoking from iOS to inject modules

```
fun initKoinIos(
  userDefaults: NSUserDefaults,
  doOnStartup: () -> Unit
): KoinApplication = initKoin {
  module {
    ...
    single { doOnStartup }
  }
}
```

```
fun initKoin(appDeclaration: KoinAppDeclaration = {}) = startKoin {
  appDeclaration()
  modules(
    platformModule,
    networkModule,
    useCaseModules,
    repositoryModule,
    commonUtils,
  )
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
fun testRepoAccess() {
     ObjFactory.appStateRepository.test() // Ok, here we are in main thread

     CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
       ObjFactory.appStateRepositoryDemo.test() //  Ok
       ObjFactory.appStateRepository.test() // Not Ok, throws exception (Must be main thread)
     }
}
```

**Expected behavior**
It should work for iOS like it works Android

`Koin 3.0.0-alpha-4`

**Additional moduleDefinition**

`Coroutines 1.4.2-native-mt`

**UPDATE**

I was using wrong Koin library name, now I'm using :

```
io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.0.1
```

and now I have another exception:

```
  kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException: illegal attempt to access non-shared org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.KoinInstanceHolder@1c02ca8 from other thread
```

Comment: did you got any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Koin on Kotlin/Native requires injection on the main thread, to avoid freezing Koin state. As a result, you can't actually inject directly from a background thread.

Adding a special inject method that would allow you to inject by switching to the main thread was intended to be added to Koin, but I'm pretty sure that never wound up in the code. Primarily because it's very rare that anybody has needed it.

So, anyway, you can't do that with Koin. You could try Kodein, but I wrote Koin's implementation to throw precisely because touching Koin from another thread will freeze everything inside it, and that may not be what you intend to do.

I know nobody likes non-answers, but why is `ObjectFactory` `@ThreadLocal`? I assume to keep it mutable, but if `appStateRepository` is a single, it would be frozen anyway.